# dropdown list webform dynamic register event in Pageload won't fire

Tags: asp.net, selectedindexchanged

I need a dynamic register event handler.
I tried to do some snippet code for ASP.NET webform and realized 'something' that makes a dropdown list won't fire event SelectedIndexChanged.

### First snippet(works well). I register the event handler in ASPX file.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="Ddl1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>

    <asp:DropDownList ID="Ddl2" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Ddl2_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:Button ID="BtnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="BtnSubmit_Click" />
</form>
```

Then in CS file, I create 2 function like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {

            Ddl2.Items.Add(new ListItem("1", "1"));
            Ddl2.Items.Add(new ListItem("2", "2"));
            Ddl2.Items.Add(new ListItem("3", "3"));
            Ddl2.Items.Add(new ListItem("4", "4"));

            Ddl1.Items.Add(new ListItem("1", "1"));
            Ddl1.Items.Add(new ListItem("2", "2"));
            Ddl1.Items.Add(new ListItem("3", "3"));
            Ddl1.Items.Add(new ListItem("4", "4"));


            BtnSubmit.Click += new EventHandler(BtnSubmit_Click);

            Ddl1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            Ddl2.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
    public void Ddl2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var st = new StackTrace();
        var sf = st.GetFrame(0);

        var currentMethodName = sf.GetMethod();
        Console.WriteLine(currentMethodName);
        Label1.Text = Ddl2.SelectedValue;
    }

    public void Ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var st = new StackTrace();
        var sf = st.GetFrame(0);

        var currentMethodName = sf.GetMethod();
        Console.WriteLine(currentMethodName);
        Label1.Text = Ddl1.SelectedValue;
    }
```

### Second, I remove Autopostback and OnSelectedIndexChanged of dropwdown 1 on view and move the register handler to PageLoad code. Now It won't fire anymore

The dropdown 1 will raise refresh page. But the event handler won't fire anymore.
I am using VS2017 Pro & .NET 4.7.2

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="Ddl1" runat="server">
    </asp:DropDownList>

    <asp:DropDownList ID="Ddl2" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Ddl2_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:Button ID="BtnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="BtnSubmit_Click" />
</form>
```

And in CS code:

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {

            Ddl2.Items.Add(new ListItem("1", "1"));
            Ddl2.Items.Add(new ListItem("2", "2"));
            Ddl2.Items.Add(new ListItem("3", "3"));
            Ddl2.Items.Add(new ListItem("4", "4"));


            Ddl1.Items.Add(new ListItem("1", "1"));
            Ddl1.Items.Add(new ListItem("2", "2"));
            Ddl1.Items.Add(new ListItem("3", "3"));
            Ddl1.Items.Add(new ListItem("4", "4"));


            BtnSubmit.Click += new EventHandler(BtnSubmit_Click);

            Ddl1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            Ddl2.SelectedIndex = 0;

            Ddl1.AutoPostBack = true;
            Ddl1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(Ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged);

        }
    }
    public void Ddl2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var st = new StackTrace();
        var sf = st.GetFrame(0);

        var currentMethodName = sf.GetMethod();
        Console.WriteLine(currentMethodName);
        Label1.Text = Ddl2.SelectedValue;
    }

    public void Ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var st = new StackTrace();
        var sf = st.GetFrame(0);

        var currentMethodName = sf.GetMethod();
        Console.WriteLine(currentMethodName);
        Label1.Text = Ddl1.SelectedValue;
    }
```

Can anyone help me:

1. What is the difference between registering the event handler on pageload or APSX file?
2. What page lifecycle event can I register to make event handler fire?
3. Is this a bug of Microsoft? If it is, where do I post this bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short, every request re-creates the page and controls.

So, "Posting Back" would load the page again but with `IsPostBack` set to `true`, and your event registration is never reached.

Comment: No, It reach if I register event in APSX file. For code behind register, It doesn't reach. It is my question guy.

Comment: You are saying exactly what I wrote. Try getting event registration out of `if` postback statement and see it for yourself.

Comment: Hi there, Thanks for your advice. Base on this behavior. This mean that in every request, The onload page run before handle_event, so onload page re-create all controls and add data to its from viewstate. Because It re-create all controls, the event-handler of new control is null, So we need to add event handler for new controls. then in event_handler. ASP.NET will fire event base on control's data and event handler. In this case, viewstate only maintain control's data without control event. Thanks so much